# How to forward emails from a domain to 2 different servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, forwarding

I am not sure the title describes my problem properly, so let me explain.

I have a domain called example.com. I have currently set it up for email services from Microsoft Live domains. I have done this primarily because I need a very small number of email addresses ( user1@example.com, user2@example.com).

However, I would like to set up a type of catch-all service for my domain so that all emails get forwarded to my server. Here, I run certain rules that determine which of them get forwarded to my primary email but I digress.

What I require is that any email that does not belong in Microsoft Live Domains be forwarded to my server so that I can handle. The main problem I face is that Microsoft does not let me add other MX servers, even after its own server and requires that it be the ONLY MX record. I thought about just forwarding some emails but I would have to make a lot of changes to the rules and I'd rather not do that.

Any suggestions? Workarounds? I can go into a lot more detail if needed.

tl;dr - Want all emails forwarded to one of 2 mx servers on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just list 2 MXes to solve this problem, because you need some email receipients to be handled by one server and some by the other server. If you just list 2 MXes, you leave it up to the remote senders' MTAs to choose an MX (randomly or according to MX priorities) and it won't work if they happen to pick the "wrong" one.

If you need to dispatch mail to different servers depending on who the recipient is with different recipients in a single domain going to different servers, then you will have to add a frontend SMTP server in front of the MXes that does the dispatching (forwarding) to one server or the other. And then you list the frontend server as your one and only MX record.